# Magento 2 How to add foreign key in update schema

Tags: magento2, install-script, table, upgradeschema

I try to add foreign key constrains for Magento 2 existing tables. I have `UpdateSchema` script but it's not working.

```
<?php

namespace Retailers\Customer\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeSchemaInterface;

class UpgradeSchema implements UpgradeSchemaInterface
{
    public function upgrade(
        SchemaSetupInterface $setup,
        ModuleContextInterface $context
    ) {
        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '2.0.1') < 0) {
            $setup->startSetup();
            $setup->getConnection();
            $setup->getTable('customer_grid_flat')
                ->addColumn(
                    'status',
                    [
                        'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_SMALLINT,
                        'length' => '11',
                        'nullable' => false,
                        'default' => '3',
                        'comment' => 'Retailers Is Allow Status',
                    ]
                )
                ->addForeignKey(
                    $setup->getFkName('customer_grid_flat', 'entity_id', 'customer_entity_varchar', 'entity_id'),
                    'entity_id',
                    $setup->getTable('customer_entity_varchar'),
                    'entity_id',
                    \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::ACTION_CASCADE
                );
            $setup->endSetup();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your module.xml version?

Comment: module version: 2.0.1

Comment: I cant find entity_id in your table,

Answer (score 16):

Try this:

```
->addForeignKey(
      $installer->getFkName('<ChildTable>', 'entity_id', '<ParentTable>', 'entity_id'),
      'entity_id',
      $installer->getTable('<ParentTable>'),
      'entity_id',
      \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::ACTION_CASCADE
)
```

> **Note:** Both table has same field and set primary key to parent table.

You are adding Foreign key to wrong table, You can not set `customer_grid_flat` table's `entity_id` as foreign key until you set primary key to `customer_entity_varchar` table's `entity_id`.

For Add foreign key with store table in Magento 2, [Check blog for add foreign key with store table](https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/how-to-add-foreign-key-in-database-table-using-magento-2/)

Comment: in case some one follow this code but not working, make sure that the 'type' of both field are the same, also both field are set to 'unsigned'.

Comment: @fudu yes, might be possible because this code was valid for magento 2.0.1 and you might be trying this on magento 2.3.x or more

Answer (score 4):

Sample for foreign key,

```
<table comment="projectfinder_attributevalue Table" engine="innodb" name="projectfinder_attributevalue" resource="default">
    <column comment="Entity Id" identity="true" name="attributevalue_id" nullable="false" padding="6" unsigned="true" xsi:type="smallint"/>
    <constraint referenceId="PRIMARY" xsi:type="primary">
        <column name="attributevalue_id"/>
    </constraint>
    <column xsi:type="int" name="option_id" padding="10" unsigned="true" nullable="false" comment="Option ID"/>
    <column name="option_value" nullable="true" xsi:type="text"/>
    <column comment="attrtbl_id" name="attrtbl_id" nullable="false" padding="6" unsigned="false" xsi:type="smallint"/>
    <column name="attribute_id" nullable="true" xsi:type="smallint"/>
    <column name="attribute_value" nullable="true" xsi:type="text"/>
    <column name="attribute_code" nullable="true" xsi:type="text"/>

    <constraint xsi:type="foreign" referenceId="ATTRIBUTE_VALUE_ID_ATTRIBUTE_TABLE" table="projectfinder_attributevalue" column="attrtbl_id" referenceTable="projectfinder_attribute" referenceColumn="id" onDelete="CASCADE"/>

    <constraint xsi:type="foreign" referenceId="ATTRIBUTE_OPTION_ID_EAV_ATTRIBUTE" table="projectfinder_attributevalue" column="option_id" referenceTable="eav_attribute_option" referenceColumn="option_id" onDelete="CASCADE"/>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

1 more important thing you need to do is make your column in foreign table is THE SAME as the column in your primary table or it will throw an error when you try to run "php bin/magento setup:upgrade", it took me a lot time to figure this out.

***For example:***

```
I have 2 table, 1 is "banner", 2 is "banner_slide", and i want to make "banner_id" in table "banner_slide" become foreign key of "id" in table "banner".
```

> table "banner"

[image]

> table "banner_slide"

[image]

Do you understand what i'm saying? You will need to make those 3 "attributes, null and default" as same as the column you want to define as foreign key.

Also, here is my code to make a foreign key, please take a look.

```
if ($installer->tableExists('banner_slide')) {
                if ($installer->tableExists('banner')) {
                    if ($installer->tableExists('slide')) {
                        $connection = $installer->getConnection();
                        $connection->addForeignKey(
                            $installer->getFkName('banner_slide','banner_id','banner','id'),
                            'banner_slide',
                            'banner_id',
                            'banner',
                            'id',
                            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::ACTION_CASCADE
                        );
                    }
                }
            }
```

And here is update code if you want to know as well.

```
if ($installer->tableExists('banner_slide')){
                $connection = $installer->getConnection();
                $tableName = $installer->getTable('banner_slide');
                $banner_id = 'banner_id';

            if($connection->tableColumnExists($tableName,$banner_id, $schemaName = null)){
                $connection->changeColumn(
                    $tableName,
                    $banner_id,
                    $banner_id,
                    ['type' => Table::TYPE_INTEGER, 'nullable' => false, 'unsigned' => true]
                );
            }

            $slide_id = 'slide_id';
            if($connection->tableColumnExists($tableName,$slide_id, $schemaName = null)){
                $connection->changeColumn(
                    $tableName,
                    $slide_id,
                    $slide_id,
                    ['type' => Table::TYPE_INTEGER, 'nullable' => false, 'unsigned' => true]
                );
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 2):

According to new update we should use [declarative schema](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/declarative-schema/db-schema.html) to create and update tables in Magento.

To add foreign key we have to add **constraint** tag for particular table

```
<schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/schema.xsd">
<table name="declarative_table">
   <constraint xsi:type="foreign" referenceId="FL_ALLOWED_SEVERITIES" table="declarative_table"
           column="severity" referenceTable="severities" referenceColumn="severity_identifier"
           onDelete="CASCADE"/>
</table>
```

Please follow instruction from official [DevDoc](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/declarative-schema/db-schema.html#create-a-foreign-key).

Answer (score 1):

In Upgrade schema do like this

```
$setup->getConnection()->addForeignKey(
                $setup->getFkName('current_table', 'current_column', $setup->getTable('parent_table'), 'parent_column'),
                $setup->getTable('current_table'),
                'current_column',
                $setup->getTable('parent_table'),
                'parent_column',
                \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::ACTION_NO_ACTION
            );
```